# Stop JMeter script after a certain time in jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, continuous-integration

While running JMeterbuild in jenkin, it run as infinite mode "never stops" even though the configuration is set in JMX. 
How to stop JMeter build after a certain time ?

I have tried to provide command line arguments thinking it isn't rewarding jmx configuration.

```
PATH/jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jduration=60 -n -t Main.jmx -l Mainreport.csv
```

Expecting JMeterbuild to stop after 60 seconds but it never ends, monitored for 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value using `${__P(duration,)}` in JMeter Scheduler's duration field:

[image]

You can add [__P default value](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in second argument, for example, for default 30

```
${__P(duration,30)}
```